# Select data from two tables with no join condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'd appreciate if someone could help. I have two tables that have no relationship:

Table_1

```
ID credittype creditamount date time
------------------------------------

1     abc           10          2016-01-18 11:29:59 am
2     def           20          2016-01-20 4:35:58 pm 
3     def           20          2016-01-21 4:35:58 pm
```

Table_2

```
ID debitetype debiteamount date time
------------------------------------

1     abc           10          2016-01-18 11:29:59 am
2     def           20          2016-01-19 4:35:58 pm 
3     def           20          2016-01-21 4:35:58 pm
```

i just want to display these tables values
like that

```
credittype creditamount debitetype debiteamount date time
---------------------------------------------------------

 abc           10                                      2016-01-18 11:29:59 am
                            def           20           2016-01-19 4:35:58 pm
 def           20                                      2016-01-20 4:35:58 pm
```

i will try this query

```
select * from Table_1 union select * from Table_2;
```

i did not get answer any one help me?

Comment: If they have no relationship, then why do you think you can just put them together? Make 2 queries.

Comment: Why do you think your UNION query doesn't work? It retrieves the data doesn't it?

Comment: just display the two tables

Comment: i did not know which query to use?

Comment: SELECT credittype, creditamount, NULL AS debittype, NULL AS debitamount, datetime FROM table1 UNION SELECT NULL AS credittype, NULL AS creditamount, debittype, debitamount, datetime FROM table2

Comment: It looks like joining on *date time* column

Answer (score 0):

Note , joining 2 table that don't have any condition not good , and it discovered that you don't design your database structure very well.

so , try like this :

select `tb1.credittype,tb1.creditamount,tb1.debitetype,tb1.debiteamount,tb1.date,tb1.time from table1,table2`

it gives you all record in table one and table two

Answer (score 0):

Using union only gets distinct values from both tables. Try using "union all" to return all values. Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp.